# Template parameters that cannot be deduced when template specification is defined

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am making a template `struct` to specify "good" and "not good" types.
I want to specify that return type of template class template method is good, but get error `Template parameters that cannot be deduced`.
Here is my current code (see on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/13xbEYYaa):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo
{
  foo(const T&, Args&&...)
  {
  };
};

template <typename T>
struct bar
{
  template <typename... Args>
  auto func(Args&&... args)
  {
    return foo<bar,Args...>(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using bar_func_return_type = decltype(std::declval<bar<T>>().func(std::declval<Args>()...));

template <typename T>
struct is_good_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_good_type<bar_func_return_type<T, Args...>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
  static_assert(is_good_type<int, float, double>::value);
  return 0;
}
```

What should I do to make desired specification, not making specification for `foo<T, Args...>` class, that is actually return type of `bar::func` method, because return type can change?

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear when something is a good type. I would probably not use that struct/std::false__type/std::good_type, but just a `static constexpre bool` function (or in C++20 a concept). These are much more readable. Another option for you might be to investigate `if constexpr`

Comment: With user specialization of `bar<T>::func<Args...>` any types might be a good_type...

Comment: @Jarod42, how? The return value is generated on the basis of `foo` template

Comment: I make it return `int`: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d4x7o1KbT). Maybe you want a trait `is_foo` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rGrc3MnEe).